# how do I return all memcached values in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memcached, python-memcached

I want to use all the data in my python app engine memcache.  I do not know the keys in advance.

How do I go about getting all data?

Comment: There does not seem to be a way to list all known keys. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: static data loaded via cron once a day.  Thinking about it, I could just pack it all into a list and give it a known key...

Comment: I posted an alternative way to list the keys via telnet over on a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611830/how-do-i-return-all-memcached-values-in-google-app-engine): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611830/how-do-i-return-all-memcached-values-in-google-app-engine

Comment: The data in memcached isn't guaranteed to stick around.  You are better off using a processor prior to the request handler to load/store the info (assuming you are using a toolkit that supports it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only read [functions](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/functions.html) available on memcache are:

```
get(key, namespace=None)

get_multi(keys, key_prefix='', namespace=None)
```

As you can see, to get data from memcache you must provide one or more keys.

Answer (score 1):

I am using a 'well known key' called "config" where I store a list of all other keys and use that to enumerate the rest of the items.

Answer (score 0):

as in comments above, I guess I could stick all data in a single memcache entry with a known key.

Still for non-static data there are scenarios where it would be useful.