# Is it possible to get all keys with prefix from GAE memcache?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memcached

I would like to do something like:

```
memcache.get_multi(ALL, key_prefix='somePrefix_')
```

in order to read every memcached key with the prefix `somePrefix_`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611830/how-do-i-return-all-memcached-values-in-google-app-engine) asks whether *all* keys can be found, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19562199/1446048) to another question offers an undocumented debugging-only method in PHP. However I don't want to `cachedump` and then find my prefix, it seems kind of hacky - and at any rate I am looking for this to stay in after development.

I tried an empty list of keys, `[]`, thinking that in the spirit of `0` being often used for 'unlimited' it might find them all. Alas, it did not.

I suspect this means it is not possible (as there is no other function to use, and I can't think how else 'all' might be represented) - but I would just like to confirm this as it makes the `key_prefix` option seem only vaguely useful, in my opinion. (When I saw it in docs, my first thought was "ah neat, I can grab everything with some prefix at once!")

Comment: If you are writing your own PHP classes then there's nothing to stop you keeping your own wildcard lists as a memcached variable.  But failing this its the tacky cachedump scan.  Sorry.

Comment: Python*. Yeah, I probably will do that since it's actually even simpler - in this case I know at 'dev-time' how many and what they are. I had hoped for a general solution though.

Comment: Typically you write a cache proxy class and use it to do all this housekeeping, then just inherit all this bumf in you individual memcached objects

Comment: @TerryE Is it better practice to have some class from which 'lookupString' or 'setString' is called, or to overload `put()` and `get()` in the `db.Model` class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope, you can only get the item if you know the key.

Comment: In that case, I don't understand why we have `key_prefix` *and* `namespace` keyword arguments. What does `key_prefix` offer beyond the illusion of a new namespace?

Comment: @OJFord I think it's just to avoid you having to hard code the same prefix string multiple times